# How to know EditText height?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to do something based on height of EditText.
How can I know EditText's height?
My code is like below.

```
<EditText  
    android:id="@+id/edit"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"       
/>

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setTextSize(20);       
    edit.setText("Hello, world");
    int height = edit.getHeight(); // this returns 0
}
```

Comment: I missed setContentView. I added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THIS IS A QUICK ANSWER: Please google.

And you can try this: aswell

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setTextSize(20);       
    edit.setText("Hello, world");       
    edit.measure(0, 0);
    int height = edit.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, there are quite a few answers about this, though most are just about getting a "view" height and width. In general, you can't get a view's dimensions that early in the creation of an activity. You need to try and grab the height during something like onWindowFocusChanged which happens after the view is constructed. However, I'm very interested in trying out what Sherif just posted :)

Comment: @leenephi It would probably be better to use a the `getTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener`. However, my answer might sometimes depend on my judgement of the level of the asker. But, still, it is always about the requirement. For example, If you need to use the height for something substantially awkward, you'd better not wait for the whole layout.

Comment: Ah, yes, because with that you can get the information as soon as it's ready, correct? I guess I just never knew that you could acquire the dimensions in onCreate.. everything I have read until now has been about picking some callback later on in the Activity, which, honestly, was frustrating because I never knew which was best  and sometimes they don't work XD  So thanks!